# Model looks different in game engine

Tags: modeling, texturing, game-engine, 3d-view

I'm a little new to Blender and I only have very basic experience with the game engine.  One thing I noticed is that some models look way different in game than in the editor window. For example,
[image: Sonic look's way different in-game]

This doesn't happen on all models, just some of them. This model was created by Sega, so I wouldn't think there would be any errors with it. Does anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: Is the scale applied to all the objects?